# Implement shuffle button for music player android app

Tags: java, android

I am trying to get my shuffle button working. But I have been unsuccessful. I commented out the code for that functionality. I am somewhat new to java Android Development and need some guidance understanding what the problem could be. Thank you for your time to help me on this.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
private boolean mIsBound = false;
private MusicService mServ;
private ServiceConnection Scon ;
Button playbutton;//play button
Button pausebutton;//pause button
Button stopbutton;//stop button
Button prevbutton;//prev button
Button nextbutton;//next button
Button randombutton;//random button
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //      this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.playinterface);

    Scon =new ServiceConnection(){

        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder
                binder) {
            mServ = ((new MusicService().new ServiceBinder()).getService());
        }

        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            mServ = null;
        }
    };



//      mServ.pauseMusic();
    //play button
    playbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    playbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
//              mp3_play();//mp3 play
//              
            Intent music = new Intent();
            music.setClass(MainActivity.this,MusicService.class);

            startService(music);
            //button enable,disabel set
            playbutton.setEnabled(false);
            playbutton.setText("Playing");
            pausebutton.setEnabled(true);
            stopbutton.setEnabled(true);
            prevbutton.setEnabled(true);
            nextbutton.setEnabled(true);
            randombutton.setEnabled(true);
//              if(mServ!=null){
//                  mServ.mPlayer.start();
//              }else{
//                  ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
//                  for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
//                        String serv = service.service.getClassName();
//                        Log.e("Danial",serv);
//                  }
//              }
        }
    });

    //pause button
    pausebutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    pausebutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
//              mp3_pause();
            Intent music = new Intent();
            music.setClass(MainActivity.this,MusicService.class);

            stopService(music);
            //button enable,disabel set
            playbutton.setEnabled(true);
            playbutton.setText("Play");
            pausebutton.setEnabled(false);
            stopbutton.setEnabled(false);
            prevbutton.setEnabled(false);
            nextbutton.setEnabled(false);
            randombutton.setEnabled(false);
        }
    });

   //stop button
    stopbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    stopbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
//              mp3_stop();
            Intent music = new Intent();
            music.setClass(MainActivity.this,MusicService.class);

            stopService(music);
            //button enable,disabel set
            playbutton.setEnabled(true);
            playbutton.setText("Play");
            pausebutton.setEnabled(false);
            stopbutton.setEnabled(false);
            prevbutton.setEnabled(false);
            nextbutton.setEnabled(false);
            randombutton.setEnabled(false);
        }
    });

//        //Prev button
    prevbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
//        prevbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
//          public void onClick(View v) {
//              
//              if(randomStart == true)//when play random
//              {
//                  Random rnd = new Random();
//                  int randIndex = rnd.nextInt(mp3_num);               
//                  if(randIndex == index_mp3)
//                  {
//                      if(randIndex == mp3_num-1)
//                          randIndex--;
//                      if(randIndex == 0)
//                          randIndex++;
//                  }
//                  
//                  index_mp3 = randIndex;
//                  mp3_play();//mp3 play
//                  return;
//              }
//              
//              if(randomStart == false)//when play into order
//              {
 //                 if(index_mp3 > 0)
//                  {
//                      index_mp3--;//select pre mp3
//                      mp3_play();//mp3 play
//                  }
//                  else{
//                      Toast.makeText(getActivity(), 
//                              "There is not prev mp3!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//                  }
//                  return;
//              }
//          }
//      });

//        //Next button
    nextbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
//        nextbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
//          public void onClick(View v) {
//              if(randomStart == true)//when play random
//              {
//                  Random rnd = new Random();
//                  int randIndex = rnd.nextInt(mp3_num);               
//                  if(randIndex == index_mp3)
//                  {
//                      if(randIndex == mp3_num-1)
//                          randIndex--;
//                      if(randIndex == 0)
//                          randIndex++;
//                  }
//                  
//                  index_mp3 = randIndex;
//                  mp3_play();//mp3 play
//                  return;
//              }
//              
//              if(randomStart == false)//wehn play into order
//              {
//                  if(index_mp3 < mp3_num -1)
//                  {
//                      index_mp3++;//select next mp3
//                      mp3_play();//mp3 play
//                  }
//                  else{
//                      Toast.makeText(getActivity(), 
//                              "There is not next mp3!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//                  }
//                  return;
//              }
//          }
//      });

//        //radmom button
    randombutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);
//        randombutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
//          public void onClick(View v) {
//              if(randomStart == false)
//              {
//                  randomStart = true;//start playing random
//                  randombutton.setText("Shuffle On");
//                  return;
//              }
//              
//              if(randomStart == true)
//              {
//                  randomStart = false;//No playing random
//                  randombutton.setText("Shuffle Off");
//                  return;
//              }
//          }
//      });

    //pause,stop button disable
    pausebutton.setEnabled(false);
    stopbutton.setEnabled(false);
//        prevbutton.setEnabled(false);
//        nextbutton.setEnabled(false);
//        randombutton.setEnabled(false);


    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager)     getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
        if    (MusicService.class.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
            playbutton.setEnabled(false);
            playbutton.setText("Playing");
            pausebutton.setEnabled(true);
            stopbutton.setEnabled(true);
            prevbutton.setEnabled(true);
            nextbutton.setEnabled(true);
            randombutton.setEnabled(true);
        }
    }


    //      //Go to the Fragment
    //      changeFragment(
    //              "PlayInterface", 
    //              R.id.frameRootContainer, 
    //              new MainActivityFragment(), 
    //              false);


}

void doBindService(){
    bindService(new Intent(this,MusicService.class),
            Scon,Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    mIsBound = true;
}

void doUnbindService()
{
    if(mIsBound)
    {
        unbindService(Scon);
        mIsBound = false;
    }
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

} 

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStop();
//      mServ.pauseMusic();
//      mServ.resumeMusic();
//      mServ.stopMusic();
}
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
}
//  public void changeFragment(String fragmentTag, int layoutId, Fragment frag, boolean addToBackStack) {
//      
//      FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();//Getting Fragment handle
//        FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();//Starting Fragment
//        
//        transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);//Setting option
//      transaction.replace(layoutId, frag, fragmentTag);//Replace the fragment
//      
//      if(addToBackStack)//put fragment on the interface
//          transaction.addToBackStack(null);
//      
//      transaction.commit();//Run
//  }
```

}

Comment: So could you please explain more about your problem? do you get any error?

Comment: I do not get an error. Maybe I am missing something or skipped a step in getting my shuffle to work. When I run the app the shuffle button simply is pressed but nothing happens. I managed to get my other buttons like Play, Pause, Stop to work. But the shuffle and the skip next and back buttons do not work :(

Comment: try my answer. hope it helps ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your shuffle button click listener just change the value of `randomStart` and this value is used in previous and next buttons(which is commented just like shuffle button click listener). If you uncomment them(prevbutton click listener and nextbutton click listener and also randombutton ) it seems your code will work without any errors.
you can see your shuffle will work when you press next or previous.

Comment: Thanks for the tip :) I uncommented everything but I get errors and ask me to create variables :( I can't find better words to explain what is happening but I thank you for your effort to help me :)

Comment: your welcome ;) I hope finally you can solve those problems.